# Two different Drupal installations on the same domain using OpenId

Tags: drupal, openid

I have two different installations on the same server that I plan to use with OpenId.

If my user connects in one site using his openid, will he be asked to login again in the other installation or will the system find the cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share user sessions across Drupal installs.

[Here's a D5 tutorial](http://drupal.org/node/147828) that should be mostly relevant. [`domain.module`](http://drupal.org/project/domain) may also accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The [Multisite login module](http://drupal.org/project/multisite_login) might be useful to do that too.